# Expression Engine - Help with category entries

Tags: php, html, variables, expressionengine

OK, I have set up channel for the client to add projects. The way it works is simple:

I have a category page that displays all of the projects from the chosen category.

I then have a title_permalink page that displays a project, on this page there are 6 most recent related projects that are from that category, each linking to a projects/view page. On this page it displays the project and again, the SAME 6 most recent related projects.

I need to change the 6 recent related projects to be 6 PREVIOUS projects (from the category) dependant on which project has been chosen? For example, I have 20 projects sorted by date entered, I click on number 11 which was entered on Friday at 09:30. I need the view page to display the PREVIOUS 6 projects (by date&time) dependant on which project page you are on.

I have searched high and low but haven't found any help. I'm not asking someone to give me the answer. I just need pointed in the right direction as to the right solution for this.

The code for my project (title_permalink) page is:

```
<div id="projectView">
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" width="980px" height="450px"}
<img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}"/>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<div id="projectView_overlay"></div>
<div id="projectView_content">
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p class="projectView_floatLeft"><b>Client:</b> {project_client} &ndash; <b>Value:</b> £{project_value} &ndash; <b>Duration:</b> {project_duration} weeks &ndash; <b>Architect:</b> {project_architect}</p>
    <p class="projectView_floatRight" style="color:#fff; font-size: 12.5px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom: 5px;">{categories}<a href="{path='projects/list'}" style="color:#fff;"><< Back to<br />{category_name}</a>{/categories}</p>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}

<br style="clear:both"/>
</div><!--END PROJECT VIEW-->

<ul id="filmStrip">
    {exp:channel:entries start_on="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}" channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
    <li>
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
    <a href="{title_permalink='projects/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
    {/exp:imgsizer:size}
    <a href="{title_permalink='projects/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
    </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul><!--END FILM STRIP-->
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one flaw in Dan's answer is that he's nesting two channel:entries tags.  That can lead to disaster. You need to embed the "related" template. Also, I think you want `stop_before`, not `start_on`. Try this modified code:

```
<div id="projectView">
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" width="980px" height="450px"}
<img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}"/>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<div id="projectView_overlay"></div>
<div id="projectView_content">
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p class="projectView_floatLeft"><b>Client:</b> {project_client} &ndash; <b>Value:</b> £{project_value} &ndash; <b>Duration:</b> {project_duration} weeks &ndash; <b>Architect:</b> {project_architect}</p>
<p class="projectView_floatRight" style="color:#fff; font-size: 12.5px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom: 5px;">{categories}<a href="{path='projects/list'}" style="color:#fff;"><< Back to<br />{category_name}</a>{/categories}</p>
</div>

<br style="clear:both"/>
</div><!--END PROJECT VIEW-->

{embed="projects/related" stop_before="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And `projects/related` looks like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! I can't thank you enough. Thanks very much to Dan also who tried to help. Could I ask, why stop_before? Am I right in saying that, by using stop_before="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"} it grabs all projects before the date of the current project then stops at the one we are currently on?

Comment: You are correct in that assumption. And because the default "orderby" is "date", and the default "sort" is "desc", it looks *backwards* from the "stop_before" date, which is exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter for the channels tag called start_on=[DATE]. I suggest you grab the entry date from the project you want to pull entries before, then use that date in your related entry tag. Note, you are using a variable `{exp:channel:entries}` to populate another channel:entries tag so it will always pull the projects you want - you are not hardcoding it.

```
{exp:channel:entries} // This tag gets your single project data
//output your project details here
{exp:channel:entries start_on="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}" channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"} // this tag grabs the last six projects relative to the single project being displayed
{make your links to the projects here}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You need to use the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM, as above.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but that wouldn't work unfortunately as i'm unaware what project they are going to click in to. I need it to pull the previous 6 projects DEPENDANT on which project they click in to.

Comment: @John-Stant - Put that code on the project page, not the page with the list of projects.

Comment: Sorry, which page do you mean? Is it the: List of projects category page or the actual project title_permalink page? I tried it on the title_permalink page and nothing happened.

Comment: @John-Stant - On the projects/view template. You need to finish the code I have given you it won't do anything on it's own. I'll edit the code a bit.

Comment: The code you gave, will only allow me to specify a date myself which will mean i'll still have the same 6 projects on every project/view page. I need the 6 previous projects dependant on the one that's been clicked on so they will change every time a user clicks a different project.

Comment: @John-Stant - No it doesn't - read the answer - you need to get the entry date variable on the projects/view page. E.g. {entry_date format="%Y %m %d"}. That tag is available within the main tag pair that pulls the single project data. You then stick it in the tag. See revised answer. The solution is sound, you just need to incorporate it into your expanded template.

Comment: Hi Dan, really appreciate your help but still can't seem to get it working, i'll put my revised code back into the original post. I get what you mean about putting that tag inside the tag that pulls the single entry but I can't seem to get everything to work together.

Comment: You probably need parse="inwards" in the channel tag, but looks like you have a solution already.